# Xen and dhcp. Not connecting

Tags: networking, xen

I'm sorry if this sounds like a really stupid question but I started today for the first time using Xen. I'm using it on a fresh installation of Debian Lenny.
I followed this tutorial http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-xen-on-debian-lenny-amd64 but the 686 version, non the amd64.

The problem is that after enabling the bridge, it can't seem able to find my router dhcp server. Is there something I'm missing? On ifconfig I have eth0, peth0 and lo.

I mean the physical computer in not connected. I can't even start creating domU because of the absence of connection.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:77:BC:E5:67  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:77ff:febc:e567/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8254 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5746 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11124971 (10.6 MiB)  TX bytes:418646 (408.8 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6198467 (5.9 MiB)  TX bytes:6198467 (5.9 MiB)

peth0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11124056 (10.6 MiB)  TX bytes:429582 (419.5 KiB)
          Interrupt:253 Base address:0xe000 

vif0.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5746 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:418646 (408.8 KiB)  TX bytes:11125224 (10.6 MiB)

vif1.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcff:ffff:feff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:32 
          RX bytes:2024 (1.9 KiB)  TX bytes:1241 (1.2 KiB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::200:ff:fe00:0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:8054 (7.8 KiB)

xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15203 (14.8 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

So apparently there is connection. The problem is in the bridge.

Comment: What response do you get from `dhclient`. Can you connect to your router if you configure the ethernet devices with static IPs?

Comment: can you show your ifconfig output as well as route output please?

Comment: @pacey: no I can't connect to anything. I can connect when I don't use xen-kernel.

Comment: additionally please post the output of `cat /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp |grep network-script`. Also check `lspci` for the network adapter. If the problem is not present under a non-XEN-kernel you should compare the output of `lsmod` for both kernels.